# Echo XML child node value based on node attribute value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I get an XML response from an API as follows:

```
$response = <<<XML
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords">
<result>
  <message>Record(s) updated successfully</message>
  <recorddetail>
    <fl val="Id">1203498000000109001</fl>
    <fl val="Created Time">2014-09-24 09:19:44</fl>
    <fl val="Modified Time">2014-09-24 11:38:08</fl>
    <fl val="Created By"><!--[CDATA[Brydges]]--></fl>
    <fl val="Modified By"><!--[CDATA[Brydges]]--></fl>
  </recorddetail>
</result>
</response>
XML;
```

If I want the message, this seems easy enough using

`$xml_response =  new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$message = $xml_response->result->message; 
echo $message;`

However, I am trying to retrieve the content of the `<fl val="id">` row e.g. 1203498000000109001.

I have looked at many questions on SO and tried all of the following that are suggested but without success:

```
//using xpath with SimpleXMLElement
$xml_response =  new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$zoho_id = $xml_response->xpath('/response/result/recorddetail/fl[@val="Id"]');
echo $zoho_id;

//using xpath with simplexml_load_string
$xml_response =  new simplexml_load_string($response);
$zoho_id = $xml_response->xpath('/response/result/recorddetail/fl[@val="Id"]');
echo $zoho_id;

//using a foreach loop
$xml_response = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
foreach ($xml_response->result->recorddetail->fl as $fl) {
 if ((string) $fl['val'] == 'Id') {
    echo (string) $fl;
  }
}

// using a foreach loop and then a switch case over the val attribute value to only echo Id
foreach ($xml_response->result->recorddetail->fl as $fl) {
    switch((string) $fl['val']) { // Get attributes as element indices
    case 'Id':
        echo (string)$fl, ' is the Id';
        break;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how I can retrieve the content I require?

FOLLOWING GHOSTS'S SUGGESTION:

print_r($doc) returns:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( 
        [uri] => /crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords 
    ) 
    [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [message] => Record(s) updated successfully 
        [recorddetail] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [FL] => Array ( 
                [0] => 1203498000000109001 
                [1] => 2014-09-24 09:19:44 
                [2] => 2014-09-24 13:06:37 
                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                    [@attributes] => Array ( 
                        [val] => Created By 
                    ) 
                ) 
                [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                    [@attributes] => Array ( 
                        [val] => Modified By 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first xpath part is already correct, the xpath results returns an array, so treat it as such:

```
$xml_response =  new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$zoho_id = (string) $xml_response->xpath('/response/result/recorddetail/fl[@val="Id"]')[0];
                                                                                    //  ^
echo $zoho_id;
// assuming you're expecting one result
```

If you have several nodes, then you can use a loop:

```
$zoho_id = $xml_response->xpath('/response/result/recorddetail/fl[@val="Id"]');
foreach($zoho_id as $node) {
    $id = (string) $node;
    echo $id;
}
```

Or:

```
$xml_response =  new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$recorddetail = $xml_response->xpath('/response/result/recorddetail');
foreach($recorddetail as $node) {
    $id_node_val = (string) $node->FL[0];
    echo $id_node_val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ghost. However the first example breaks the whole script (seems to be to do with the [0] at the end according to Dreamweaver validation and the 2nd does not work either I am afraid.

Also, if I remove the [0] from the first example and then try the following I get unexpected results: 

'$xml_response =  new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$zoho_id = (string) $xml_response->xpath('/response/result/recorddetail/fl[@val="Id"]');
var_dump($zoho_id);'

Comment: @JBReading well based on your example, this was the working one, here [check out the demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Etav19)

Comment: @JBReading unless of course (which doesn't make sense) the one you posted on the question that i was testing was not really the xml you're working with

Comment: We might be onto something here. I have used the codepad example you provided directly in my script and this works, however as soon as I try and use the response from the curlrequest to the API it does not work. 

The XML I pasted above is what I thought I was getting from the API response as this is what I go to echo page when I do this: `$response = $utilObj->sendCurlRequest(TARGETURL, $parameter); print_r($response);`

Comment: @JBReading so this was coming from an external source.. hmm.. thats why i was wondering why it doesn't work. are you sure `$response` is an xml string? and the same with the one on the question above?

Comment: I have checked that this is an XML string using the method suggested by @Tjirp here: http://goo.gl/xHYwfu and received no errors:

`libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = simplexml_load_string($response);
$xml = explode("\n", $response);

if (!$doc) {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo display_xml_error($error, $xml);
    }

    libxml_clear_errors();
}
else {
   print_r($doc);
}`

Results of print_r($doc) are in my question due to space here.

Comment: @JBReading looking at the response, my code should return empty, the first `<fl>` has no `val="id"` attribute

Comment: @JBReading based on the response, (which is `val="id"`) is missing, if the only determining factor is that if the id will always fall into index zero, then check my revision, should be fairly straightforward

Comment: You were almost there but we both missed that the problem node shown in the print_r was FL not fl. So the following now works, assuming Id is always position 0 in the array: `$xml_response =  new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$recorddetail = $xml_response->xpath('/response/result/recorddetail');
foreach($recorddetail as $node) {
    $id_node_val = (string) $node->FL[0];
    echo $id_node_val;
}
`

I had used fl as this is what seemed to be produced by the earliest print_r of response. Also, where does the print_r get the attributes for val from?

Comment: @JBReading oh okay, wrong index should be upper case `FL`, thats why i was wondering earlier, the codes and the sample xml doesn't match, the reason is really they aren't really the same

Comment: @JBReading anyways, im glad it turned out well in the end, glad some of this helped

Comment: Much appreciated @Ghost. Still not sure where the FL val attribute values come from, but at least it works for now :-)